# JsonManagedReference for maps

Tags: json, jackson

In Jackson it is possible to define a link between parent and child objects via
@JsonManagedReference  and @JsonBackReference  as in

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    public List<Item> userItems; 
    } 

    public class Item {
    public int id;
    public String itemName;

    @JsonManagedReference
    public User owner; 
 }
```

would is be possible to have the same link if the children were stored in a map, like:

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    public Map<String, Item> userItems; 
} 

public class Item {
    public int id;
    public String itemName;

    @JsonManagedReference
    public User owner; 
 }
```